# Parsing a string to an array in C#

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have this string :

```
string resultString="section[]=100&section[]=200&section[]=300&section[]=400";
```

I just want the numbers to be stored in the array `result[]` like

```
result[0]=100
result[1]=200
result[3]=300
result[4]=400
```

Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: so you want to skip second position in the array? And how you determine which one to skip?

Comment: actually I got that string from textbox, so clarity I just represented as a string

Comment: So make it a string, just because its an example, doesn't give you a reason to be lazy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
NameValueCollection values = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("section[]=100&section[]=200&section[]=300&section[]=400");
string[] result = values["section[]"].Split(',');
// at this stage 
// result[0] = "100"
// result[1] = "200"
// result[2] = "300"
// result[3] = "400"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
str.Split('&')
   .Select(s=>s.Split('=')
               .Skip(1)
               .FirstOrDefault()).ToArray();
```

OR

```
 str.Split(new[] { "section[]=" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(s => s.Replace("&", ""))
    .Select(Int32.Parse).ToArray();
```

OR

```
        var items = new List<string>();
        foreach (Match item in Regex.Matches(str, @"section\[\]=(\d+)"))
            items.Add(item.Groups[1].Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
        string s ="section[]=100&section[]=200&section[]=300&section[]=400";
        Regex r = new Regex(@"section\[\]=([0-9]+)(&|$)");

        List<int> v = new List<int>();

        Match m=r.Match(s);
        while (m.Success){
            v.Add(Int32.Parse(m.Groups[1].ToString()));
            m=m.NextMatch();
        }

        int[]result = v.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string x = "section[]=100&section[]=200&section[]=300&section[]=400";

// Split into a list
string[] vals = x.Split('&');
List<int> results = new List<int>();
foreach (string aResult in vals)
{
    int result = 0;
    string[] val = aResult.Split('=');

    // Get right hand side
    if (val.Length == 2 && int.TryParse(val[1], out result))
        results.Add(result);                    
}
```